# Enable the mobile view in window phone 8.1 sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, mobile

When i'm try to access the sharepoint 2010 in iphone, i getting the mobile version but in windows phone i'm getting desktop version not mobile version. This here ant thing i need to change in compat.browser.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a mobile browser and device model like below:

1. Start IIS Manager by typing INETMGR at a command prompt.
2. Right-click the IIS Web site where the SharePoint Web application is installed, and then click Explore.
3. In Windows Explorer, double-click the App_Browsers folder.
4. Open the compat.browser file in a text editor.
5. Find the  node.
6. Add a new  node to the end of the list of browsers.
7. Save your changes to the compat.browser file.
8. Restart IIS by entering the following command at the command prompt: `iisreset /noforce`.

Here is a detailed article for your reference:
[Configuration Mobile Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393832(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying the compat.browser (as those modifications may get overwritten by patches) it's a better practice to create your own .browser file (with a name that's alphabetically later than compat.browser and hence will override it) and add a new browser node for Windows Phone 8.1 to that.

See this blog for details - [Managing Customizations to ASP.NET and SharePoint Browser Definitions](http://sharepoint.smayes.com/2011/11/managing-customizations-to-asp-net-and-sharepoint-browser-definitions)

To force the load of your new file you don't need to do an IIS reset (which won't help at all), but you do need to touch the built-in compat.browser, which will force a recompile of the definition files, see this MSDN blog for details - [Safari 7.1 on MAC Computers causes multiple Issues with SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2014/10/27/safari-7-1-on-mac-computers-causes-multiple-issues-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx) - "Important" note right at the bottom.